# ¿Cómo usar varios estilos y que cada uno tenga su propia fuente para ser usados en los Textview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ya importé las fuentes a assets/fonts/fuente1.tff - fuente2.tff pero no se cómo llamarlas en styles.xml

```
   <style name="style1">
    <item name="android:typeface">fuente1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12pt</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>/> 
   </style> 

   <style name="style2">
    <item name="android:typeface">fuente2</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14pt</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00F0</item>/>
  </style>
```

Comment: Hola, los has solventado? otra manera para realizar eso seria usando la librería  Spanny https://github.com/binaryfork/Spanny

Comment: Recuerda de marcar la respuesta correcta sí ha cumplido su cometido

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la propiedad `style` de tu `TextView` para cargarlo:

```
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Este es mi TextView"
            style="@style/mi_style" />
```